# Create a thread to make a function sleep without freezing the program

Tags: multithreading, qt, sleep, freeze

I'm new in QT, I'm trying to create a program that read data from a serial port and create a plot, in that plot a new dot in set every ten seconds, I've used the function QThread::sleep(10); to make the program sleep, but this freeze all the window so i can't close it or doing anything else.

```
   void MainWindow::Reader()
{
  //Letura dei dati
  serial->waitForReadyRead();
  m_readData=serial->QSerialPort::readAll();
  //Sgrossatura dei dati
     inter=QString(m_readData);
    QStringList firstlist2= inter.split("$");
    m_readData2=firstlist2.takeFirst();
    inter2=QString(m_readData2);
    QStringList firstlist3= inter2.split(" ");
    m_readData3=firstlist3.takeFirst();
    H=m_readData3.toDouble();
    QStringList firstlist4=inter2.split(" ");
    m_readData4=firstlist4.takeLast();
    T=m_readData4.toDouble();
    //Ottenere dal timer la variabile tempo
      double milli=timer.elapsed();
      double sec=milli/1000;
      double min=sec/60;
      double ore=min/60;
      //Creazione dei punti
        addPoints(H,T,min);
        //Aggiunta dei punti ai grafici
          PLOTTER_H();
          PLOTTER_T();
          //Programma in stand-by per 5 minuti
          int a=10000;
            QThread::sleep(10);           //300
}
```

Can anybody help me?`enter code here`

Comment: The usual way to do this sort of thing in Qt is with a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Connect its timeout signal to a function that updates your plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "blocking" operation `serial->waitForReadyRead()` in gui thread, it will freeze gui thread until serial receives any data. Instead connect `QSerialPort::readyRead` to slot and read data there. This way you don't need any timers or sleeps at all. If you invoke `QThread::sleep()` in gui thread event loop freezes - no mouse or keyboard events got recieved all widgets got not responsive.

I'd suggest moving `QSerialPort` to worker wich runs in separate thread to improve code clarity.